# Dynamically style android app

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app that will be used by multiple clients, and each client will want this app to be styled differently (right now mostly they'll swap colors and fonts).

We want the app to be used by as many clients that building the app for each one of them, and or creating separate `theme.xml` file at built time would be cumbersome.

Application uses an REST api extiensively, and easiest way for us would be just to download either `theme.xml` from the api or just download some JSON and then turn it to XML.

**So the question is:**

Can I load dynamically generated style to android application (or modify current style on runtime). If this is possible tell me how :)

At best I would like it to work without manually overriding color for each attribute for every widget I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible right now.